# how to make a dinamic sql request based on user input from six textboxes in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am making a search refiner for my application and i'm currently making a query which returns the relevant listings based on the form a user has filled in. The problem is that the forms fields are optional and I cannot figure out how to make my lookup change based upon which fields are entered.

Comment: Without your code, nobody can give any good help

Comment: Please check the [ask]

Answer (score -1):

What we do is in SQL is do the following:

```
Select * from table where 
    (ISNULL(@field1, '') = '' OR @field1 = table.field1) 
    and (ISNULL(@field2, '') = '' OR @field2 = table.field2)  
    and (ISNULL(@field3, '') = '' OR @field3 = table.field3)  
    and (ISNULL(@field4, '') = '' OR @field4 = table.field4)  
    and (ISNULL(@field5, '') = '' OR @field5 = table.field5)  
    and (ISNULL(@field6, '') = '' OR @field6 = table.field6)
```

or in VB

```
dim sql as string = "Select * from table where 
    (ISNULL(" & textBobx1.text & ", '') = '' OR " & textBobx1.text & "= table.field1) 
    and (ISNULL(" & textBobx2.text & ", '') = '' OR " & textBobx2.text & "= table.field2)  
    and (ISNULL(" & textBobx3.text & ", '') = '' OR " & textBobx3.text & "= table.field3)  
    and (ISNULL(" & textBobx4.text & ", '') = '' OR " & textBobx4.text & "= table.field4)  
    and (ISNULL(" & textBobx5.text & ", '') = '' OR " & textBobx5.text & "= table.field5)  
    and (ISNULL(" & textBobx6.text & ", '') = '' OR " & textBobx6.text & "= table.field6)"
```

You just need to pass all fields through making sure that if the field on the form is not filled in pass through a blank or could call afunction that you pass in the text box text and it returns NULL.

Comment: This is open to SQL injection. You should **always** use parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I just added a couple of single quotes and it worked perfectly fine!